# Java Webservice - Expert Know How

Tags: java, web-services, console-application, apache-axis

I have written an axis2 java webservice. This service works perfektly on a Apache Tomcat

Please let me know if it is possibly to make some tasks in a webservice automatically.

Is there any technical solution available to combine a webservice and a normal java application in one component?

For example the application has some functions which are reachable as webservice and on the other side the application listen for new sockets or do other stuff beside the webservice functions

So it is a application with a Web service inside. .

Thanks for your expert know how. ..

BR

Answer (score -1):

SO is really not meant for recommending tools but what you need is an "embedded servlet container". There are a couple to choose from. The first is Jetty http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ also take a look at "embedded Tomcat"

Instead of using an embedded servlet container you could keep the whole thing running in tomcat but implement a ServletContextListenter that runs on startup that you could start your socket listeners in.